# Getting Interval Server Error with java.lang.NullPointerException while trying to access JPA Respository in Spring Boot Application

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, crud

I am scratching my head on a problem and I am not able to get any solutions. I am fairly new to Spring Boot and developing a small project on it. My application will have only 2 tables. I have one table named `product_metrics` and my JPA entity for the table looks like-

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "product_metrics")
public class ProductMetric extends Auditable<String> {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@NotNull
@Column(name = "product_id", unique = true)
private Long productId;

@Column(name = "bundle_quantity")
private BigDecimal bundleQuantity;

@Column(name = "length_in_cm")
private BigDecimal lengthInCm;

@Column(name = "breadth_in_cm")
private BigDecimal breadthInCm;

@Column(name = "height_in_cm")
private BigDecimal heightInCm;
```

}

Now the problem statement is I want to fetch all the products given product_ids in an array. So I have decided to use POST Api call as i don't want to break url limit if large number of product_ids are send by using GET api. The problem that I am facing is I am getting internal server error as soon as my JPA Repository is hit.

My Controller is -

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
public class ProductMetricController extends BaseController {

@Autowired
private ProductDetailService productDetailService;

@PostMapping("/product-details")
public ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>> getProductDetails(@RequestBody Map<String, List> requestParam) {
    Map<String, Object> responseMapper = new HashMap<>();

    try {
        if (requestParam.containsKey("product_ids")) {
            responseMapper = productDetailService.fetchProductList(requestParam);
        }

        return new ResponseEntity<>(responseMapper, HttpStatus.OK);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        responseMapper.put("message", e.getMessage());
        return new ResponseEntity<>(responseMapper, e.getClass().getAnnotation(ResponseStatus.class).value());
    }

}
}
```

My Service is-

```
@Service
public class ProductDetailServiceImpl implements ProductDetailService{

@Autowired
private ProductMetricRepository productMetricRepository;

public  Map<String, Object> fetchProductList(Map<String, List>  requestBody) {

    Map<String, Object> responseMapper = new HashMap<>();
    List<Long> productIds = requestBody.get("product_ids");

    Optional<List<ProductMetric>> productList = productMetricRepository.findAllByProductIdIn(productIds);
    if ( productList.isPresent() ) {
        List<ProductMetric> productMetricsList =  productList.get();
        for (ProductMetric metrics : productMetricsList) {
            responseMapper.put(metrics.getId().toString(), metrics);
        }
        return responseMapper;
    } throw new ResourceNotFoundException(ExceptionMsgs.PRODUCT_LIST_NOT_FOUND);
}
}
```

And my JPA respository is -

```
@Repository
   public interface ProductMetricRepository extends JpaRepository<ProductMetric, Long> {

   Optional<List<ProductMetric>> findAllByProductIdIn(List<Long> productIds);
}
```

I am hitting the POST request with Request Body-

```
{
   "product_ids": [
       12345,
       66052
   ]
}
```

The problem that i am facing is i am getting Internal Server error with java.lang.NullPointerException as -

```
java.lang.NullPointerException\n\tat
    com.bizongo.logistics.controllers.ProductMetricController.getProductDetails(ProductMetricController.java:32)\n\tat
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
    Method)\n\tat
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)\n\tat
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\n\tat
    java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)\n\tat
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)\n\tat
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)\n\tat
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106)\n\tat
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:888)\n\tat
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793)\n\tat
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)\n\tat
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)\n\tat
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)\n\tat
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)\n\tat
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)\n\tat
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)\n\tat
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)\n\tat
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)\n\tat
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)\n\tat
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\n\tat
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)\n\tat
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\n\tat
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\n\tat
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)\n\tat
    org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:118)\n\tat
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)\n\tat
    org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)\n\tat
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)\n\tat
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)\n\tat
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)\n\tat
    org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:158)\n\tat
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)\n\tat
    org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)\n\tat
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)\n\tat
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:154)\n\tat
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\n\tat
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)\n\tat
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)\n\tat
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)\n\tat
    org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:92)\n\tat
    org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:77)\n\tat
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\n\tat
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)\n\tat
    org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)\n\tat
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)\n\tat
    org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)\n\tat
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\n\tat
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)\n\tat
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)\n\tat
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)\n\tat
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358)\n\tat
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271)\n\tat
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\n\tat
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\n\tat
    org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:108)\n\tat
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\n\tat
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\n\tat
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\n\tat
    org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)\n\tat
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\n\tat
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\n\tat
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\n\tat
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)\n\tat
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)\n\tat
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)\n\tat
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)\n\tat
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)\n\tat
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)\n\tat
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)\n\tat
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:367)\n\tat
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)\n\tat
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:860)\n\tat
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1598)\n\tat
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)\n\tat
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)\n\tat
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)\n\tat
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)\n\tat
    java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)\n"
```

---

If you guys can help me then it would be a great great help. Sorry for any silly mistake that i would have done and Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: .getProductDetails(ProductMetricController.java:32)\, what is at line 32 in ProductMetricController.java......

Comment: Where is your datasource, entitymanager?

Comment: Simply put an `@AUtowired` field cannot be `null` if that happens your application wouldn't even start. So you either are constructing the controller yourself in some convoluted way that Spring cannot inject the dependencies, or there is something else and you aren't showing the actual code and the fact that you reduced the complexity doesn't show the issue.

Comment: List<Long> productIds = requestBody.get("product_ids"); Have you checked (productIds) if it is null or not :)

Comment: You are missing an `@RequestBody` annotation on your `Map` in your method. Hence nothing will be there.

Comment: this is causing because of  **Optional<>**. it need to be handled to avoid NullPointerExceptions.

Comment: try to print some logger comment in your code. so you will come to know where it is failing. ryt?